# Validate XML without XSD

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd

I  have an XML file coming in and need that to have a few specific tags without that I cannot process that file. How can I make sure if those tags are there or not , I tried using the XSD validation but file format keeps changing and they keep sending additional tags which I do not need  to process the file , but having those additional tags does not harm my process.

Is there a way to write the XSD in a way that it only looks for a few tags and ignore the others?

Comment: If it is well formed xml, you can load the xml into an XDocument then use linq to query for the elements that you are interested in. If an element is not present the query will return null. You can also use .Any() in your linq query which returns a bool to determine if elements exist.

Comment: And, speaking of `Any`, `<xs:Any/>` can be added to an XML Schema to make it less fussy about what it's reading.  It will match anything that shows up at it's level in the schema.

Comment: @Flydog57 - Does Any needs to be added at all of the sequence level?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an xsd in which you have all of the elements you require. By default an element has `minOccurs=1`, which would imply that it's required. Then in order to ignore all of the rest you need to add `<xs:any processContents="lax" macOccurs="unbounded"/>`, which basically says that the xml may contain any number of additional elements which do not need to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider forgoing an XSD and instead writing XPath checks against the XML to test known-invariant properties of your XSD.   XSD is better for when you have a known, relatively static grammar.  Ad hoc XPath assertions or Schematron would be better for XML that can't be held do a definitive grammar.